# how do i send blob from visual basic 2005 to mysql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, pdf, blob

Hello i was reading and yet don't know how to save a pdf in mysql with visual basic 2005, so, i'm asking for advices/samples i need to have this doc saved in mysql and accesible for all logged users

Comment: step back and ignore the pdf: you're saving binary data. so your question should be "how do I send a blob from VB to mysql".

Comment: ok i will change that

Comment: What data type would you use? How would you store the binary file into the database? How would you retrieve this value from the database?

Comment: i don't know yet, that's why i'm asking your advice, any ideas sir ??

Comment: If your blobs can be greater than 16 MB then you're best off with LONGBLOB, see [The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html). For the VB part I recommend using prepared statements. Have a try at it.